# Creating a Banded Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, diagonal

I am trying to convert a Matlab code creating a banded diagonal matrix. The Matlab code I'm trying to convert is:

```
N = 5;
e = ones(N-1, 1);
D = spdiags([-e 2*e -e], [-1 0 1], N-1, N-1);
D = full(D);
```

The output of the above Matlab code, D =

```
 2    -1     0     0
-1     2    -1     0
 0    -1     2    -1
 0     0    -1     2
```

The closest C++ attempt I get at converting it is the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
vector< vector<double> > bandedMat(vector<double> &e,int N);

int main()
{
   int N = 5 ;
   vector<double> e = {-1,2,-1};
   vector< vector<double> > B = bandedMat(e,N);

   return 0;
}
vector< vector<double> > bandedMat(vector<double> &e,int N)
{
   vector< vector<double> > D(N-2, vector<double>(N,0.0));
   double val = 0.0;

  for(int i = 0; i < D.size(); i++)
  {
     for(int j = 0; j < e.size(); j++)
     {
        val = e[j];
        D[i][i+j] = val; // Put along the diagonal of matrix D. Note the    index.
     }
  }

  return D;
}
```

The output of my following C++ code is D=

```
-1  2 -1  0  0
0  -1  2 -1  0
0  0  -1  2 -1
```

As you can see, my C++ version is quite different, it produces D to be 3x5 as opposed to the Matlab Version which produces D to be 4 x 4. Also, the diagonals of my C++ version are a little bit different. Can someone point out on how can I get the exact D like the Matlab version.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. Better yet: Learn to write unit tests (for `bandedMat()`). Even better: Develop your code, i.e. `bandedMat()`, using [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). My *guess* is that `bandedMat()` is called with the wrong parameters *or* that `D` is initialized with the wrong parameters. But why guessing when your computer can check this for you automatically. And this kind of automation is a unit test.

Comment: its ok, i've resolved the problem

Comment: Care to share your knowledge? Then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i think its not elegant, at least it solved my problem for now. Here it is:

```
vector< vector<double> > bandedMat(vector<double> &e,int N)
{
    // Do some checking, Only tridiagonals are allowed.
    if(e.size()>3)
    {
        cout << "Only tridiagonals are allowed. Input vector to function must be only 3 elements." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    vector< vector<double> > D(N-1, vector<double>(N-1,0.0));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < D.size(); i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < D.size(); j++)
        {
            if(i == j)
            {
                D[i][j] = e[1]; // put value of e[1] as the main diagonal of D
            }
        }
    }

    int j =0; // index
    int k =0; // index

    for(size_t i =0; i < D.size()-1;i++)
    {
        D[i][j+1] = e[0]; // put value e[0] as the upper diagonal
        j = j+1;
    }

    for(size_t i =0; i < D.size()-1;i++)
    {
        D[i+1][k] = e[2]; // put value of e[2] as the lower diagonal
        k = k+1;
    }

    return D;
}
```

An exact matrix like the Matlab version will be produced. If Anyone has a better idea or a more elegant way to do it, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

slightly more elegant... you could put all three in just one loop

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < D.size(); i++)
{
    if (i<D.size()) {
        D[i][i+1] = e[0];
    }
    D[i][i] = e[1]; // put value of e[1] as the main diagonal of D
    if (i>0) {
        D[i][i-1] = e[2];
    }
}
```